# How to access a zip file inside a jar-archive using Java NIO 2

Tags: java, jar, zip, java-7, nio2

i'd like to access a zip file that is located inside of a jar archive. I thought that i should be possible with the capabilities of NIO 2, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Does somebody know how and if it is possible?

I already read that it wasn't possible before NIO 2 without extracting the zip file first and i also read that the TrueZIP library offers this function. But i'd like to solve the problem with the "native" abilities of Java.

Best regards,

David

Comment: what do you want to do with the zip? Extract it? Extract a part of the zip?

Comment: It is possible without NIO2 using ZipInputStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Path jarPath = Paths.get(...);
try (FileSystem jarFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jarPath, null)) {
    Path zipInJarPath = jarFS.getPath("/foo/myZip.zip");
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I can even write into the file (in my case, a WAR file!