# How to save ZIP file from HttpURLConnection response

Tags: java, spring, httpurlconnection

I am trying to save the zip file i am receiving from a service call . Below is the code i am trying to save it . Am not getting any error but not getting the extension .

```
ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\RandD\\IC");// not allowing 
me to save as IC.zip
FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

What is the correct way to save the zip file . Looking for most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy from an URL - pointing to a file, namely a ZIP file - to the file system you can use [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) (which exists since [Java 7](https://javaalmanac.io/jdk/8/apidiff/7/)):

```
try (var is = url.openStream()) {
  Files.copy(is, Path.of("C:/RandD/IC.zip"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

This code should work with Java 11 ++ and in Java 8, this could be:

```
try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
  Files.copy(is, Paths.get("C:/RandD/IC.zip"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Even if you want to do something more complicate (eg: [open the ZIP file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177497/how-to-access-a-zip-file-inside-a-jar-archive-using-java-nio-2), in which case you can use ... Java NIO2 to do so), you don't need to use channels for that.

Comment: Thanks , But is there any way we can replace if the same name file exists while coping. Eg . if IC.zip is exists just replace it . Currently it throwing exception

Comment: See update => StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING